# Javascript, spliced FileReader for large files with Promises, how?

Tags: javascript, promise, filereader, chain

I'm trying to use FileReader to read several files sequentially using promises for that. The problem is that I need to divide the reading operations in several chunks to make them doable. By doing so, I lose the Promise chain. This is what happen in the following code, where I get the console log `here`, then `catched` (meaning I've lost the chain), then `inside` and then `finished`. Somehow the Promise in upload is not respected.

Here it is the code (please go to the last EDIT, I keep the original text nonetheless)

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(e) {
  if (e.target.readyState == 2) {
    console.log('inside')
    start = temp_end;
    temp_end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
    if (temp_end > end) temp_end = end;
    upload();
  }
};

Array.reduce(function(promise, item) {
  start = 0;
  temp_end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
  end = parseInt(totalsize);
  if (temp_end > end) temp_end = end;
  uploading_file = item;
  return upload()
  .then(function(){
    console.log('not shown');
  })
  .catch(console.log('catched'));
},0);

function upload() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    if (start < end) {
      console.log('here')
      var chunk = uploading_file.slice(start, temp_end);
      reader.readAsBinaryString(chunk);
    } else {
      console.log('finished')
      uploading_file = null;
      resolve();
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT1: new code I'm trying, still the console.log `stop 1` appears before the `upload` and the `here 2`

```
        var start = 0;
        var temp_end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
        var end = parseInt(item.size);
        if (temp_end > end) temp_end = end;
        uploading_file = item;
        console.log('here 1')
        Promise.resolve().then(function() {
            return upload();
        })
        .then(function(){
            console.log('here 2')
        })
        .catch(console.log('stop 1'));

        function upload() {
            console.log('upload')
            if (start < end) {
                var chunk = uploading_file.slice(start, temp_end);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunk);
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    if (e.target.readyState == 2) {
                        start = temp_end;
                        temp_end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
                        if (temp_end > end) temp_end = end;
                        return upload();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                console.log('finished')
                uploading_file = null;
                return Promise.resolve();
            }
         }
```

EDIT2: The catch logs were there due to a lack of function(). The following code seems to work, but I cannot see the value `content` that I am interested at the end.

The problem is that promises are indeed not working here, the console.log says

```
here 1
here 2
here 4
here 3
```

The code:

```
        var item; // item is a file
        var BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 100000;
        var start = 0;
        var temp_end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
        var end = parseInt(item.size);
        if (temp_end > end) temp_end = end;
        var content = ''; // to be filled by the content of the file
        var uploading_file = item;
console.log('here 1');
        Promise.resolve().then(function() {
console.log('here 2');
            return upload();
        })
        .then(function(content){
console.log('here 4');
            console.log(content); // this is empty (!!)
        })
        .catch(function(){
            console.log('stop 1')
        });

        function upload() {
            if (start < end) {
                var chunk = uploading_file.slice(start, temp_end);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunk);
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    if (e.target.readyState == 2) {
                        content += new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(e.target.result);
                        start = temp_end;
                        temp_end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
                        if (temp_end > end) temp_end = end;
                        return upload();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                uploading_file = null;
                console.log(content); // it shows the content of the file
console.log('here 3');
                return Promise.resolve(content);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm finding it really hard to understand what you're trying to do. You have a lot of undeclared variables, shared state, and incorrect code (`Array.reduce`? Is `Array` actually a variable in your real code?). And `upload` seems to have nothing to do with uploading and the returned promise sometimes doesn't resolve or reject. I'll take a stab at guessing the attempt, but if you could clarify exactly what the purpose of the code is.

Comment: Please go to the last EDIT for the final code. In any case, the Array.reduce was meant to mean that I had an array and that I used the reduce, but this part of the code is indeed not important for the problem I want to isolate. I hope with the last code it is clearer what I want to achieve? The final goal is to read files by chunks and to keep the control of this through promises

Comment: Much clearer now, thanks.

Comment: @GWorking is that worked, seems this guy needs the same solution like your's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57206375/multifile-upload-as-chunks

Comment: @Jayavel I've dropped a link to this question, I haven't been working with file uploads since ... 2 years ago, a little bit rusty down here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `upload()` function does not always return a Promise. It does in the *else* condition, but the if condition doesn't. You have a return statement, but it's inside of a *callback*, so it won't be received by the caller of `upload`.

Try changing that to this:

```
function upload() {
  if (start < end) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var chunk = uploading_file.slice(start, temp_end);
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunk);
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        if (e.target.readyState == 2) {
          content += new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(e.target.result);
          start = temp_end;
          temp_end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
          if (temp_end > end) temp_end = end;
          resolve(upload());
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    uploading_file = null;
    console.log(content); // it shows the content of the file
    return Promise.resolve(content);
  }
}
```

Now, `upload` always returns a Promise instead of `undefined`.

Comment: Fantastic. This is it. Thousand thanks! I am troubling now by using a Array.reduce here. Since this has been nicely solved, I'm opening a new question for that, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822187/javascript-uploading-several-files-within-an-array-reduce-with-promises-how, in case you have time